# define a function to return specified type of std::variant c++

Tags: c++, c++17, variant, std-variant

I am almost new to using c++17 rules. My question is straightforward; how can I access the std::variant types in the same order I defined them? Something like the following code that I know is not working!

```
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>

using myVariant = std::variant<double, int, std::string>;

template<typename T>
T   typeReturn(int i);

int main(void)
{
    myVariant b = 1.2;

    double c = typeReturn(1)(b);

    std::cout << c << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

template<typename T>
T typeReturn(int i)
{
    if (i == 0) return std::get<double>;
    else if (i == 1) return std::get<int>;
    else if (i == 2) return std::get<std::string>;
    else return std::get<int>;
}
```

Comment: `typeReturn(1)(b);` -> `std::get<1>(b);`. That function already exists, it's `std::get`. The numbering starts from 0.

Comment: @KamilCuk this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: @KamilCuk might be worth an answer, or at least I can't quickly find a duplicate of this one.

Comment: BTW, `std::visit` is the way to go: `std::visit([](const auto& e){ std::cout << e << std::endl; }, c);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how can I access the std::variant types in the same order I defined them?

No need to write it yourself - [`std::get` already does that](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get). Just:

```
double c = std::get<0>(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but I suppose you're looking for something as follows

```
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>

using myVariant = std::variant<double, int, std::string>;

template <std::size_t I>
auto typeReturn (myVariant const & v)
 {
        if constexpr ( I == 0 ) return std::get<double>(v);
   else if constexpr ( I == 1 ) return std::get<int>(v);
   else if constexpr ( I == 2 ) return std::get<std::string>(v);
   else                         return std::get<int>(v);
}

int main ()
 {
   myVariant b = 1.2;

   double c = typeReturn<0u>(b);

   std::cout << c << std::endl;
 }
```

Observe that you need use `if constexpr` and pass the index as template parameter.

Comment: But they also don't need to write this function at all, since it already exists as `std::get<>()`.